# Why do I get metadata service request related HTTP exceptions when using AWS CLI (in debug mode) to list a publicly available bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I'm using the AWS CLI on my server (my server *isn't an EC2 instance*) to list the contents of an open data set on an AWS S3, and it works fine:

```
$ aws --no-sign-request s3 ls s3://commoncrawl/cc-index/table/cc-main/warc/crawl=CC-MAIN-2013-20/
     PRE subset=warc/
```

But when I use `--debug` to see what's happening behind the scenes, I see exceptions caused by timeouts, such as:

```
2020-06-02 14:08:14,945 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - Caught retryable HTTP exception while making metadata service request to http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
  File "urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
  File "urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
socket.timeout: timed out
```

and:

```
2020-06-02 14:08:15,948 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - Caught retryable HTTP exception while making metadata service request to http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone/: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone/"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
  File "urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
  File "urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
socket.timeout: timed out
```

It's working, in the sense that it's returning the proper response from the S3 bucket, but why do I see those exceptions in the bucket mode? Why does boto complain for the

- http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token: Connect timeout on endpoint
- http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone/: Connect timeout on endpoint

The version of AWS CLI that I use:

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/2.0.17 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.3.0-45-generic botocore/2.0.0dev21
```

I run AWS CLI on an Ubuntu GNU/Linux server 19.10.

Is there a way to prevent those exceptions? I'm asking this because I'm using the same `aws cli` utility to connect to **non-AWS object stores**, too. In this case there's no concept of "**IAM**" with respect to such S3-compatible object storage. This is why I'm trying to understand if I can make `aws cli` skip that part.

The **full debug output**:

```
$ aws --debug --no-sign-request s3 ls s3://commoncrawl/cc-index/table/cc-main/warc/crawl=CC-MAIN-2013-20/
2020-06-02 14:24:31,488 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/2.0.17 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.3.0-45-generic botocore/2.0.0dev21
2020-06-02 14:24:31,489 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['--debug', '--no-sign-request', 's3', 'ls', 's3://commoncrawl/cc-index/table/cc-main/warc/crawl=CC-MAIN-2013-20/']
2020-06-02 14:24:31,489 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_timestamp_parser at 0x7ff2e8f5a598>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,489 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function register_uri_param_handler at 0x7ff2e98a6268>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,489 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_binary_formatter at 0x7ff2e8f1da60>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,489 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_assume_role_provider_cache at 0x7ff2e985f840>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,491 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function attach_history_handler at 0x7ff2e90a40d0>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,491 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_json_file_cache at 0x7ff2e90d89d8>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,491 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.s3: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x7ff2e8f619d8>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,492 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.s3.anonymous: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7ff2e8e9f400>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,492 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.ls: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x7ff2e8f619d8>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,493 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.ls.paths: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7ff2e8e9f400>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,493 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.ls.anonymous: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7ff2e8e9f400>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,493 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.ls.page-size: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7ff2e8e9f400>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,494 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.ls.human-readable: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7ff2e8e9f400>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,494 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.custom.ls: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x7ff2e9830940>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,494 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.ls.summarize: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7ff2e8e9f400>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,494 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.custom.ls: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at 0x7ff2e9830940>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,494 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.custom.ls.request-payer: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x7ff2e8e9f400>
2020-06-02 14:24:31,496 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTP connection (1): 169.254.169.254:80
2020-06-02 14:24:32,498 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - Caught retryable HTTP exception while making metadata service request to http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
  File "urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
  File "urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "botocore/httpsession.py", line 263, in send
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 725, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 379, in increment
  File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 735, in reraise
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1229, in request
  File "botocore/awsrequest.py", line 92, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
  File "botocore/awsrequest.py", line 119, in _send_output
  File "botocore/awsrequest.py", line 203, in send
  File "http/client.py", line 956, in send
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 187, in connect
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 167, in _new_conn
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPConnection object at 0x7ff2e8e3b470>, 'Connection to 169.254.169.254 timed out. (connect timeout=1)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "botocore/utils.py", line 221, in _fetch_metadata_token
  File "botocore/httpsession.py", line 287, in send
botocore.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token"
2020-06-02 14:24:32,499 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTP connection (2): 169.254.169.254:80
2020-06-02 14:24:33,500 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - Caught retryable HTTP exception while making metadata service request to http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone/: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone/"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
  File "urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
  File "urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "botocore/httpsession.py", line 263, in send
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 725, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 379, in increment
  File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 735, in reraise
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1229, in request
  File "botocore/awsrequest.py", line 92, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
  File "botocore/awsrequest.py", line 119, in _send_output
  File "botocore/awsrequest.py", line 203, in send
  File "http/client.py", line 956, in send
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 187, in connect
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 167, in _new_conn
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPConnection object at 0x7ff2e8e3b748>, 'Connection to 169.254.169.254 timed out. (connect timeout=1)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "botocore/utils.py", line 264, in _get_request
  File "botocore/httpsession.py", line 287, in send
botocore.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone/"
2020-06-02 14:24:33,501 - MainThread - awscli.utils - DEBUG - Max number of attempts exceeded (1) when attempting to retrieve data from metadata service.
2020-06-02 14:24:33,501 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: env
2020-06-02 14:24:33,502 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2020-06-02 14:24:33,502 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role-with-web-identity
2020-06-02 14:24:33,502 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: sso
2020-06-02 14:24:33,502 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2020-06-02 14:24:33,503 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2020-06-02 14:24:33,503 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/2.0.17/dist/botocore/data/endpoints.json
2020-06-02 14:24:33,510 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7ff2ea856bf8>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,517 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/2.0.17/dist/botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/service-2.json
2020-06-02 14:24:33,527 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_post at 0x7ff2ea8a4bf8>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,527 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7ff2ea8a49d8>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,532 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
2020-06-02 14:24:33,539 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/2.0.17/dist/botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/paginators-1.json
2020-06-02 14:24:33,540 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event provide-client-params.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function base64_decode_input_blobs at 0x7ff2e8f222f0>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,541 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function set_list_objects_encoding_type_url at 0x7ff2ea878158>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,541 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function validate_bucket_name at 0x7ff2ea874ea0>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,541 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_cache of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7ff2e89b66d8>>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,541 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <bound method S3ArnParamHandler.handle_arn of <botocore.utils.S3ArnParamHandler object at 0x7ff2e89b6a20>>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,541 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x7ff2ea874ae8>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,542 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-call.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function add_expect_header at 0x7ff2ea877268>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,542 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-call.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.set_request_url of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7ff2e89b66d8>>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,542 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-call.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function inject_api_version_header_if_needed at 0x7ff2ea878510>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,542 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Making request for OperationModel(name=ListObjectsV2) with params: {'url_path': '/commoncrawl?list-type=2', 'query_string': {'prefix': 'cc-index/table/cc-main/warc/crawl=CC-MAIN-2013-20/', 'delimiter': '/', 'encoding-type': 'url'}, 'method': 'GET', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'aws-cli/2.0.17 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.3.0-45-generic botocore/2.0.0dev21'}, 'body': b'', 'url': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/commoncrawl?list-type=2&prefix=cc-index%2Ftable%2Fcc-main%2Fwarc%2Fcrawl%3DCC-MAIN-2013-20%2F&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url', 'context': {'client_region': 'aws-global', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x7ff2e89b62b0>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': None, 'encoding_type_auto_set': True, 'signing': {'bucket': 'commoncrawl'}}}
2020-06-02 14:24:33,542 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event request-created.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7ff2e89b6240>>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,542 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-signer.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x7ff2ea8749d8>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,542 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-signer.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function disable_signing at 0x7ff2ea8771e0>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,542 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-sign.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <bound method S3EndpointSetter.set_endpoint of <botocore.utils.S3EndpointSetter object at 0x7ff2e89b6a90>>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,543 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - Defaulting to S3 virtual host style addressing with path style addressing fallback.
2020-06-02 14:24:33,543 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - Checking for DNS compatible bucket for: https://s3.amazonaws.com/commoncrawl?list-type=2&prefix=cc-index%2Ftable%2Fcc-main%2Fwarc%2Fcrawl%3DCC-MAIN-2013-20%2F&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url
2020-06-02 14:24:33,543 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - URI updated to: https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&prefix=cc-index%2Ftable%2Fcc-main%2Fwarc%2Fcrawl%3DCC-MAIN-2013-20%2F&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url
2020-06-02 14:24:33,543 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=GET, url=https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&prefix=cc-index%2Ftable%2Fcc-main%2Fwarc%2Fcrawl%3DCC-MAIN-2013-20%2F&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url, headers={'User-Agent': b'aws-cli/2.0.17 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.3.0-45-generic botocore/2.0.0dev21'}>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,544 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com:443
2020-06-02 14:24:33,988 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com:443 "GET /?list-type=2&prefix=cc-index%2Ftable%2Fcc-main%2Fwarc%2Fcrawl%3DCC-MAIN-2013-20%2F&delimiter=%2F&encoding-type=url HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2020-06-02 14:24:33,989 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response headers: {'x-amz-id-2': 'd83WTlBDKacMBr+0ReHHYaZmErezzMJxNvTChfrzCeF8gc9SFPcUGX59R7Qk3KSG3kpaK+OM/jI=', 'x-amz-request-id': 'AF67B94BB8A77A9F', 'Date': 'Tue, 02 Jun 2020 14:24:34 GMT', 'x-amz-bucket-region': 'us-east-1', 'Content-Type': 'application/xml', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Server': 'AmazonS3'}
2020-06-02 14:24:33,989 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response body:
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"><Name>commoncrawl</Name><Prefix>cc-index/table/cc-main/warc/crawl%3DCC-MAIN-2013-20/</Prefix><KeyCount>1</KeyCount><MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys><Delimiter>/</Delimiter><EncodingType>url</EncodingType><IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated><CommonPrefixes><Prefix>cc-index/table/cc-main/warc/crawl%3DCC-MAIN-2013-20/subset%3Dwarc/</Prefix></CommonPrefixes></ListBucketResult>'
2020-06-02 14:24:33,990 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <bound method RetryHandler.needs_retry of <botocore.retries.standard.RetryHandler object at 0x7ff2e89b69e8>>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,990 - MainThread - botocore.retries.standard - DEBUG - Not retrying request.
2020-06-02 14:24:33,990 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <bound method S3RegionRedirector.redirect_from_error of <botocore.utils.S3RegionRedirector object at 0x7ff2e89b66d8>>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,990 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function decode_list_object_v2 at 0x7ff2ea878268>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,991 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <function enhance_error_msg at 0x7ff2e8f5a1e0>
2020-06-02 14:24:33,991 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event after-call.s3.ListObjectsV2: calling handler <bound method RetryQuotaChecker.release_retry_quota of <botocore.retries.standard.RetryQuotaChecker object at 0x7ff2e89b6630>>
                           PRE subset=warc/
```

Comment: That's how boto3 gets instance metadata for determining instance IAM roles. It's only attempted if all other methods of getting IAM credentials fail. This configuration method applies to all official AWS sdks (AFAIK). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#config-settings-and-precedence

Comment: I'm using the same `aws cli` utility to connect to non-AWS object stores, too. In this case there's no concept of "IAM" with respect to such S3-compatible object storage. This is why I'm trying to understand if I can make aws cli skip that part.